# A Hamiltonian graph contains at least two vertices of degree $\geq 3$

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove the following statement:

**Suppose $G$ is a (simple) Hamiltonian graph with at least $4$ vertices. If $G$ is *not* a cycle, then it contains at least two vertices of degree $\geq 3$.**

Intuitively this makes a lot of sense and I tried using induction on the number of vertices of the graph in order to get a result, but I got stuck and don't know how to proceed. If $G$ has $4$ vertices, then it is either $K_4$ or $K_4^-$ (by which I mean the complete graph on $4$ vertices, and the complete graph on $4$ vertices minus an edge, respectively). So in this case (the base case of the induction) it is obvious that $G$ contains at least two vertices of degree $3$.

How do I go on from there? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think induction is your best approach, although people often achieve interesting and surprising results with methods I consider unpromising.

Here we know that there is a Hamiltonian circuit. Take one example of such and since $G$ is not a cycle graph there must be at least one other edge which connects two points but is not part of that cycle - giving the two end points of that edge degree of (at least) $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_0v_1 \ldots v_{n - 1} v_0$ be an Hamiltonian cycle of $G$.
Since $G$ is not a cycle, there must be a vertex $v_i$ that has a neighbor $v_j$ distinct from $v_{i - 1}$ and $v_{i + 1}$ (take indices modulo $n$).
But then, both $v_i$ and $v_j$ have degree at least $3$.

Answer (score 1):

As $G$ is Hamiltonian, $G$ contains a cycle subgraph $C_{n}$. Remove the edges of the Hamiltonian cycle from $G$. As $G$ is not a cycle, there are edges remaining. An edge connects two vertices. So selecting an edge, the two vertices incident to said edge have degree at least $3$ in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What does the fact that the graph is Hamiltonian tell you? What more do you get from the fact that it isn't a cycle? [Where does this not work when there are fewer than four vertices?]

This is a classic make sure you have read the question and got the most out of each piece of what you are told. Ask yourself how you are using each piece of information.